# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Constructed Languages's [first moderator election](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: jknappen]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Adarain who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5214513747984384/0).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the community for their trust in me.  I hope I can do some good work here.

Comment: Herzlichen Glückwunsch!

Comment: Yay! Go now and rule with a fist of iron and a rod of adamant!

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations Jknappen! Welcome to the team! Thank you too to Oliver Mason for putting your hand up.

And thank you Adarain for your service over the past year.